# NestJS Prisma: start application even if prisma can't connect to database

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, prisma, prisma2

I'm trying to prevent prisma from from shutting my app down even if it fails to connect to the database, so that my `health-check` endpoint can still be reached. The error I get is this:

```
          throw new PrismaClientInitializationError(error2.message, this.config.clientVersion, error2.error_code);
                ^
Error: Can't reach database server at `postgres`:`5432`

Please make sure your database server is running at `postgres`:`5432`.
    at startFn (/home/my_name/my_folder/my-service/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:27186:17)
    at Proxy.onModuleInit (/home/my_name/my_folder/my-service/src/services/prisma.ts:12:5)
```

which makes sense, because my database is shut off. But this crashes my nest application.
The [prisma docs say that the PrismaClientInitializationError](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/error-reference#prismaclientinitializationerror) is returned when`prisma.$connect` runs, or if a query is run.

The obvious solution to me was to wrap `this.$connect` with a try catch to prevent it from crashing and burning. So here is my attempt in my `PrismaService` - the file that the error above is complaining about `my-service/src/services/prisma`:

```js
import { INestApplication, Injectable, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PrismaClient, Prisma } from '@prisma/client';

@Injectable()
export class PrismaService
  extends PrismaClient<Prisma.PrismaClientOptions, 'query' | 'error'>
  implements OnModuleInit
{
  constructor() {
    try {
      super();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
  async onModuleInit() {
    this.$on('error', (event) => {
      console.log(event.target);
    });
    try {
      await this.$connect();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  async enableShutdownHooks(app: INestApplication) {
    this.$on('beforeExit', async () => {
      await app.close();
    });
  }
}
```

It's littered with console logs, and none of them log anything to the console. In fact, I found that even if I **delete** `this.$connect` if my database is up and running then prisma still connects to the database. If my database is not running I still get the same error message as above.

My question is, where do I need to put a try catch in order to prevent prisma from breaking my app?

And to satisfy my curiosity, why is the prisma client seemingly initializing itself even if I don't run `this.$connect`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has seemingly resolved itself. and my error handling now works. I'm suspecting that because I was using `docker compose` with mounted volumes some sort of caching was getting in the way and not registering that I had put a try/catch there